# Is it possible to stack a partially transparent png image on top of a fullscreen video (mp4) div background, using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the following css method to deploy a fullscreen background video to my homepage that takes up the entire viewport.  I would like to lay a transparent repeating (tiling) static .png background image over the top of the video.  Is this possible?

```css
video#bgvid {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-image: url(videobg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width: auto;
 height: auto; 
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop poster="videobg.jpg" id="bgvid">
 <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
 <source src="videobg/videobg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But the overlay has to be a separate element that is positioned absolutely over the video, not as a background-image property.

Comment: Although an absolute div with a width, height and background could be overlaid. This is common practice on sites with fullscreen background videos, they often have a logo or caption overlaid.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, it is not possible to let a background image "show through" the content of its opaque parent element (regardless of how negative the `z-index` the content is set to), because it belongs to the background. The solution would be to wrap your `<video>` element in a parent element, say `<div>`, position the parent in the way you want, and append a child element (hence a sibling of the video) that acts as the overlay.

In my example I have used a random video I found on Vimeo and embedded it, so you can actually see the result live:

```css
#bgvid {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
#bgvid video,
#bgvid div.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#bgvid video {
  z-index: 1;
}
#bgvid .overlay {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="bgvid">
  <video autoplay loop poster="videobg.jpg">
    <source src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4" type="video/webm">
      <source src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, works great. Appreciate the help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

You will need to have a wrapping element around the video and the overlay.

```
<div id="videowrapper">
    <!-- Video and Overlay -->
</div>
```

And then the video code plus the overlay.

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<video autoplay loop poster="videobg.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="videobg/videobg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

With CSS set the wrapper to be fullscreen and `position:relative;` . Then set the overlay to be `position:absolute;` , given a fixed width and height to force it to size and then apply the desired background image.

```
#videowrapper {
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

#overlay {
    position:absolute;
    width:30%;
    height:200px;
    top:15%;
    z-index:999; /* make sure its above the video */
}
```

For example.